# Get value by index. but with limited function (user defined function)

Tags: java

There are only these 4 methods:

- `addFirst()` -> add item at index 0.
- `addLast()` -> add item at last index.
- `removeFirst()` -> remove first item.
- `removeLast()` -> remove last item.

The following code is that I tried so far, but I can't make the queue same as the initial queue:

```
public static int get(Deque queue, int index) throws Exception {

    int value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        if (value != 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < index; j++) {
                queue.addFirst(value);
            }
        }
        value = queue.removeFirst();
    }

    System.out.print(value);
    System.out.println();
    return value;
}
```

I need to get the value of the arraylist by the index

Comment: Hi, could you please give us information what you have already implemented and what is the exact problem? Currently your question looks like asking for a ready solution, but it's not like the Stack Overflow works :)

Comment: Your code shows `Deque`, but you ask about `ArrayList` - which is it?

Comment: @AndyTurner the function is already given. you cant use the build in library

Comment: @AndyTurner there are class `Deque` with constructor creating `ArrayList`

Comment: @AndyTurner you will need to use an additional queue that will be used to preserve items that have been removed from initial queue.

Comment: @Kamil really? Why not just use the iterator?

Comment: @AndyTurner because you have written that you can use only following methods: addFirst(),  addLast(), removeFirst(), removeLast().

Comment: the problem is i cant use the `new` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response, but I think that I've found a solution for your problem. You don't need to use any additional queue to store items of original queue. What can be solution for you, is to modify your for-loop. 
You can do it like this:

1. Create variable for method result.
2. Create additional temporary variable to store currently processed queue item.
3. Iterate through all queue items performing following operations

   1. Remove first queue item and assign it to the temporary variable.
   2. Add temporary variable to the end of the queue.
   3. If current loop index is the same as one passed as the method parameter assign value of the temporary variable to the result variable.
4. Return result variable.

It's not the perfect solution, because you will have to check if expected index is not less than 0 or greater than queue size, but it should give you basic skeleton of solution and allow you to preserve original for of input queue.

Code that can be used to implement steps described by me will look as follows

```
public static int get(Deque<Integer> queue, int index) throws Exception {
    Integer value = null;
    Integer currentValue = null;
    int queueSize = queue.size();

    for (int i=0; i<queueSize; i++) {
        currentValue = queue.removeFirst();
        queue.addLast(currentValue);
        if (i == index) {
            value = currentValue; 
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Please notice that I've added type declaration to the queue parameter (`Deque<Integer> queue), as without it you would have to cast value returned by`queue.removeFirst()`` to Integer/int in your loop.